# Changing radii of circles in a circle packing?

Tags: circle-packing

I have a collection of packed circles $\mathcal C = \{{C_i}\}_i$ obtained by the Koebe-Andreev-Thurston circle packing theorem.

For each circle $C_i$ I have its position $p_i = (x_i, y_i)$ and its radius $r_i$. Some of the circles are touching themselves (the connections forms a planar graph).

Now, I want to resize a circle a subcollection of circles $S \subset \mathcal C$ to a certain diameter $R$. So each $r_i$ can be less or greater than $R$.

So the 1st question is: is this even possible. If I only want to resize one circle to size $R$, does there even exists a packing obtained from the original one? (I guess one would need to somehod dynamically push all the others. How do I compute the other centers and radii then I make circle with radius $r_i$ bigger, e.g. $r_i + \epsilon$?

2nd question: how do I achieve the desired result? Some dynamics? Slowly chaning the packing until the desired result?

Comment: "Now, I want to resize a circle a subcollection of circles  ⊂  to a certain diameter " makes no sense. Also, what does "Some of the circles are touching themselves (the connections forms a planar graph)" mean? (How does a circle touch itself?) Also, the word "changing" is spelled with two Gs.

Comment: You can always resize the circles with a Mobius transformation... If the graph is triangulated, then this is the only degree of freedom according to the same theorem you quote. If not, then there is certainly flexibility. As a simple example, consider a chain  of circles with tangency graph equal to a cycle. Then it's pretty clear that the radii can be arbitrary.